# How to prevent result and input data from vanishing while using form submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to prevent the result in the p tag and the input from date from vanishing after showing the output for a second after I submit the form because later a secondary program is unable to read the data from the p tag.

Please help!!

```js
function Adate(){
    var edate= document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var res = document.getElementById("result");
    var tday = new Date();
    var bdate = new Date(edate);
    var agedate= tday.getFullYear() - bdate.getFullYear();
    if(agedate>=0)
    {
        res.textContent ="You are "+agedate ;
    }
    else
    {
        res.textContent ="You are from the future!!";}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return Adate()">
        Enter your DOB: 
        <input type="date" id = "dob" >
        <input type="submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
    <p id="result"> 
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: try to use .,return false; when is not sended

Comment: We can call Adate function when submit button is clicked and remove onsubmit from form but doing this html body is changed. :(

Comment: @prabin badyakar can't do that but thanks for the advice anyway :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I'll try that...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `return false;` to the end of the function `Adate()`, and this should do the trick:

```js
function Adate(){
    var edate= document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var res = document.getElementById("result");
    var tday = new Date();
    var bdate = new Date(edate);
    var agedate= tday.getFullYear() - bdate.getFullYear();
    if(agedate>=0)
    {
        res.textContent ="You are "+agedate ;
    }
    else
    {
        res.textContent ="You are from the future!!";}
    return false;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return Adate()">
        Enter your DOB: 
        <input type="date" id = "dob" >
        <input type="submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
    <p id="result"> 
    </p>
</body>
```

Here, `return false;` basically means that the page will not try submitting the form to some backend, hence it will not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

My variant

```js
var edate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var res = document.getElementById("result");
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function Adate() {
  var tday = new Date();
  var bdate = new Date(edate);
  var agedate = tday.getFullYear() - bdate.getFullYear();
  if (agedate >= 0) {
    res.textContent = "You are " + agedate;
  } else {
    res.textContent = "You are from the future!!";
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
      form.submit();
    },
    4000
  );
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return Adate()">
  Enter your DOB:
  <input type="date" id="dob">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p id="result">
</p>
```

Comment: You've changed the HTML; from the OP (in bold there also): "**It is important that anything within the body tag should not be changed**".

Comment: I changed my js code. And not changed HTML (by code in question)

Comment: You realize we can see the edit history, right? At the time I wrote that comment, you had changed the HTML.

Comment: You're talking about <body>?

Comment: You had removed the `onsubmit` attribute of the `form` element in the initial answer, and change the submit button to a `button` element.

Comment: Now HTML code as in the question. I said that.